# Need Urdu language Support

Tags: language

I am new to civicrm and want to use civicrm for our NGO. Our donors would be interested in viewing the funding data in urdu. Is there urdu support available? if not please guide me as to how i can work towards changing civicrm to support our urdu data and in the end showing it on the web and/or mobile app.

Thanks

Comment: I haven't been involved in translations but googling brings up a lot of links for civicrm. I think it uses Transifex and you can see the options here. https://www.transifex.com/civicrm/civicrm/ (and no Urdu is not on there)

Comment: Thanks, very kind of you to comment. I ll check it out.